# Laravel / Eloquent - how to ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to sort my query results based on a series of slash-separated ids (from the URL, e.g. /10/25/1). I grab the URL segments and `explode` them to get an array with elements `10, 25, 1`. Now, I want my SQL to be something like this:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`products`.`id`, 10, 25, 1)
```

In Eloquent, I'm trying to do this:

```
->orderByRaw('FIELD(`products`.`id`, ?)', [implode(', ', $product_ids)])
```

But that outputs something like this:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`products`.`id`, "10, 25, 1")
```

I could declare a variable, loop through my array, and build the string `10, 25, 1` and just use that variable in place of the `?` -- however, I would not be getting the benefit of whatever Eloquent does to prevent SQL injection attacks.

**Suggestions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each parameter needs to have its own placeholder.

You can implode placeholders and pass the array as a parameter:

```
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($product_ids), '?'));

->orderByRaw("FIELD(`products`.`id`, $placeholders)", $product_ids)
```